# javascript array into a C# NameValueCollection

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

From an aspx/jqGrid screen, I need to send selection criteria to the server.
What I have are several text boxes--and an Input button --

```
<asp:TextBox ID="kPID" runat="server" CssClass="tbBlock" Width="50px" />
           <asp:TextBox ID="kLN" runat="server" CssClass="tbBlock" />
           etc...
           <asp:Button ID="InputEnter_Button" runat="server"  
             OnClientClick="Client_InputEnterClick"   OnClick="InputEnter_Click" />
```

But the onClientClick seems not to work...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function LookupGrid_Client_InputEnterClick() {
            var formValues = { kPID: $("#kPID").val(), kLN: $("#kLN").val(), kFN: $("#kFN").val(), 
                   kBD: $("#kBD").val(), kPhone: $("#kPhone").val(), kStreet: $("#kStreet").val() };
            $('#LookupGrid').setGridParam({ postData: formValues });
        }
    </script>
```

So I extended with serializeGridData --

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $.extend($.jgrid.defaults, {
        serializeGridData: function(data) {
            var kkPID = document.getElementById($("[id$=_kPID]").attr("id")).value;
            var kkLN = document.getElementById($("[id$=_kLN]").attr("id")).value;
            etc...
            var formValues = { kPID: kkPID, kLN: kkLN, kFN: kkFN, kBD: kkBD, kPhone: kkPH, kStreet: kkST };
            return "{'PECLookupArgs':'" + JSON.stringify(formValues) + "'}"; 
        }
    });
</script>
```

Then jqgrid used a GET function Async, and now I can get URL values --

```
<trirand:JQGrid ID="LookupGrid" runat="server" Height="300px" Width="50%" LoadOnce="true"
    OnDataRequesting="LookupGrid_DataRequesting"  >
and code behind ...
protected void LookupGrid_DataRequesting(object sender, Trirand.Web.UI.WebControls.JQGridDataRequestEventArgs e)
{
    NameValueCollection qscoll = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(Request.QueryString.ToString());
```

Which has 3 keys, the last one being null (aside: why is it null?) --

```
?qscoll[null]
"{'PECLookupArgs':'{\"kPID\":\"\",\"kLN\":\"\",\"kFN\":\"\",\"kBD\":\"\",\"kPhone\":\"\",\"kStreet\":\"\"}'}"
```

I have tried do it the longhand way --

```
    NameValueCollection myCol = new NameValueCollection();
    string[] myTerms = myUnesc.Split(',');
    foreach (string aTerm in myTerms)
    {
        string[] myPair = aTerm.Split(':');
        string key = myPair[0];
        string var = myPair[1];
        myCol.Add(key, var);
    }
```

But the  \" are still there... there's gotta be a better way.  Wot now?

Comment: Can you post the rendered output of `<asp:Button ID="InputEnter_Button" runat="server"  
             OnClientClick="Client_InputEnterClick"   OnClick="InputEnter_Click" />`  Trying to fill in the gaps in your code snippets

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss  I have abandoned those events.  I have a  Global
        protected void Application_BeginRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e)    {    requestCounter += 1;  and have found the InputEnterClick happens on an earlier Request than the DataRequesting Request, ergo no way to communicate between them.